# Problems Populating TableView with NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using SudzC for an iPhone app. I'm succesfully calling my ASP.Net webservice and pulling the needed data into an NSMutable array called tableData.  I have a tableView that should display the contents of tableData; however this is not working. I've looked for hours at this problem.  I'm very new to the Objective C world so I'm thinking it's a small oversight on my part.  I've linked my TableView to the ViewController (delegate/datasource) as well.

Here's is the code I have:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DocumentServiceJSONService.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
NSMutableArray *tableData;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    DocumentServiceJSONService* service = [[DocumentServiceJSONService alloc] init];
    [service GetAllEMSDocumentsXMLAsString: self action:@selector(handleGetAllEMSDocuments:)];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) handleGetAllEMSDocuments:(id) result {

  if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        //if an error has occurred, handle it
        return;
    }

    if([result isKindOfClass: [SoapFault class]]) {
        return;
    }

    NSString* xmlString = result;


    CXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:xmlString options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *nodes = NULL;
    nodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//EMSDocuments" error:nil];

    for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) {
        NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        int counter;

        for (counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {
        [item setObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[node childAtIndex:counter] name]];
        }
    //[item setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"DisplayName"] stringValue] forKey:@"DisplayName"];
        NSString *displayName = [item objectForKey:@"DisplayName"];
        [tableData addObject:displayName];
    }


}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have in your .h the delegate and datasource correctly set:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

And if you are using XIBs for the user interface, that the tableview is connected to the File's Owner as datasource and delegate.
[image]

--
EDIT:
Creating a Outlet for you tableview:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have both of those set up.  I'm using a StoryBoard in my application and have designated the TableView datasource and delegate to ViewController.

Comment: Have you inserted NSLog inside any of the tableview functions to see if they are being called?

Comment: I've set some breakpoints and it seems that my tableData count returns 0 in the numberOfRowsInSection method... my tableData count was 5 earlier, but it seems to call this method before tableData gets populated.  Do I need to move my method calls elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, the ideia is for you to separate the call to the webservice in a NSObject class with a callback. Then you only load the tableview data once the webservice gets called and returns the information. Your webservice call may delay due to a number of factors that may cause the tableview not to load.

Comment: one other option is to call [tableview reloadData] once the webservice returns the data. That way the functions will be called again and your tableview will be populated

Comment: I've tried [tableView reloadData] however, I already get the message "Unknown receiver 'tableView', did you mean UITableView?".

Comment: You need to create an Outlet for your tableview. If you're using XIB, open the Assistent Editor to load the .h in a split view and control connect to anywhere in there. Then you will create an Outlet. Choose the name you want, if you name it tableView, then [tableView reloadData]  will work. Or if you did not create the synthetize for the tableView, you can use [_tableView reloadData].

Comment: What if I'm using a StoryBoard and not a .xib file?

Comment: Same thing, open the assistant editor on the top (the icon in the middle with a butler tie)

Comment: Hmm, I can now called [self.tableView reloadData], however still shows nothing.  My tableData still has 0 objects in it, even though I successfully added 5 objects to it earlier.

Comment: Well after a lot of hunting around there was a connection problem in my Storyboard which ultimately fixed the issue.  Thanks for your direction, it was very helpful.